# Is there method faster than np.isin for large array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, isin

For large array(n>1e8), is there any faster way than `np.isin` for checking whether there are same elements?

I have tried several method like pandas `isin`, cython but all of those takes more time than `np.isin`

example: (Test whether each element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array)

```
num = int(1e8)
a = np.random.rand(int(num))
b = np.random.rand(int(num))

ref=time.time()
ainb = np.isin(a,b)
print(a[ainb])
print(time.time()-ref,'sec')
```

```
>>> [0.23591019 0.46102523]
>>> 65.45570135116577 sec
```

Comment: I'm not good at English. If there are some grammar mistakes, I'd appreciate your understanding.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a drop-in (for your use-case) but possibly faster replacement for [`np.isin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), you could use Python `set()` for the checking and accelerate the explicit looping in Numba:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def is_in_set_nb(a, b):
    shape = a.shape
    a = a.ravel()
    n = len(a)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    set_b = set(b)
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] in set_b:
            result[i] = True
    return result.reshape(shape)
```

Note that there is some (cheap) extra code to make it work for N-dim arrays which you could probably omit if you only need 1D.

This could even be made faster by adding further parallelization:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def is_in_set_pnb(a, b):
    shape = a.shape
    a = a.ravel()
    n = len(a)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    set_b = set(b)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        if a[i] in set_b:
            result[i] = True
    return result.reshape(shape)
```

This comes up quite much faster than `np.isin()`, `set()` intersection and an `is_in_set()` solution without Numba acceleration:

```
def is_in_set(a, b):
    set_b = set(b)
    return np.array([x in set_b for x in a])
```

With input sizes of ten million elements:

```
n = 10 ** 7
k = n // 3
np.random.seed(0)
# note: I used `int`s because I wanted to be able to control the collisions
a = np.random.randint(0, k * n, n)
b = np.random.randint(0, k * n, n)


%timeit ainb = np.isin(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 3.94 s per loop
%timeit ainb = is_in_set_nb(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 814 ms per loop
%timeit ainb = is_in_set_pnb(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 740 ms per loop
%timeit ainb = is_in_set(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 7.69 s per loop
%timeit set(a).intersection(b)  # not a drop-in replacement
# 1 loop, best of 3: 6.79 s per loop
%timeit set(a) & set(b)  # not a drop-in replacement
# 1 loop, best of 3: 8.98 s per loop
```

and with hundred million elements (the last two approaches ended up filling all memory and are therefore omitted):

```
n = 10 ** 8
k = n // 3
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0, k * n, n)
b = np.random.randint(0, k * n, n)


%timeit ainb = np.isin(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1min 4s per loop
%timeit ainb = is_in_set_nb(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 13.1 s per loop
%timeit ainb = is_in_set_pnb(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop
%timeit ainb = is_in_set(a, b); a[ainb]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2min 5s per loop
```

---

Adding more timings for smaller inputs but all combinations of lengths of `a` and `b`:

```
funcs = np.isin, is_in_set_nb, is_in_set_pnb
sep = '    '
print(f'({"n=len(a)":>9s},{"m=len(b)":>9s})', end=sep)
for func in funcs:
    print(f'{func.__name__:15s}', end=sep)
print()
I, J = 7, 7
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        n = 10 ** i
        m = 10 ** j
        a = np.random.randint(0, m * n, n)
        b = np.random.randint(0, m * n, m)
        print(f'({n:9d},{m:9d})', end=sep)
        for func in funcs:
            result = %timeit -q -o func(a, b)
            print(f'{result.best * 1e3:12.3f} ms', end=sep)
        print()
```

```
( n=len(a), m=len(b))    isin               is_in_set_nb       is_in_set_pnb      
(        1,        1)           0.011 ms           0.001 ms           0.047 ms    
(        1,       10)           0.048 ms           0.001 ms           0.023 ms    
(        1,      100)           0.050 ms           0.002 ms           0.027 ms    
(        1,     1000)           0.102 ms           0.007 ms           0.041 ms    
(        1,    10000)           0.766 ms           1.028 ms           1.122 ms    
(        1,   100000)           9.717 ms           3.426 ms           3.356 ms    
(        1,  1000000)         105.154 ms          43.642 ms          40.734 ms    
(       10,        1)           0.010 ms           0.001 ms           0.023 ms    
(       10,       10)           0.030 ms           0.001 ms           0.023 ms    
(       10,      100)           0.053 ms           0.002 ms           0.027 ms    
(       10,     1000)           0.100 ms           0.007 ms           0.055 ms    
(       10,    10000)           0.961 ms           1.031 ms           1.154 ms    
(       10,   100000)           9.772 ms           3.595 ms           3.761 ms    
(       10,  1000000)         105.802 ms          54.260 ms          50.265 ms    
(      100,        1)           0.010 ms           0.001 ms           0.024 ms    
(      100,       10)           0.030 ms           0.002 ms           0.025 ms    
(      100,      100)           0.054 ms           0.002 ms           0.026 ms    
(      100,     1000)           0.105 ms           0.008 ms           0.045 ms    
(      100,    10000)           0.751 ms           1.076 ms           1.158 ms    
(      100,   100000)           9.824 ms           3.253 ms           3.329 ms    
(      100,  1000000)         105.697 ms          57.993 ms          55.285 ms    
(     1000,        1)           0.012 ms           0.005 ms           0.028 ms    
(     1000,       10)           0.038 ms           0.006 ms           0.029 ms    
(     1000,      100)           0.119 ms           0.007 ms           0.033 ms    
(     1000,     1000)           0.180 ms           0.014 ms           0.063 ms    
(     1000,    10000)           0.821 ms           1.074 ms           1.169 ms    
(     1000,   100000)           9.920 ms           3.392 ms           3.532 ms    
(     1000,  1000000)         104.666 ms          57.845 ms          54.603 ms    
(    10000,        1)           0.020 ms           0.041 ms           0.092 ms    
(    10000,       10)           0.089 ms           0.088 ms           0.158 ms    
(    10000,      100)           0.967 ms           0.112 ms           0.182 ms    
(    10000,     1000)           1.017 ms           0.161 ms           0.249 ms    
(    10000,    10000)           1.633 ms           1.137 ms           1.283 ms    
(    10000,   100000)          10.754 ms           3.027 ms           3.302 ms    
(    10000,  1000000)         101.926 ms          48.062 ms          49.117 ms    
(   100000,        1)           0.071 ms           0.409 ms           0.455 ms    
(   100000,       10)           0.575 ms           0.916 ms           0.803 ms    
(   100000,      100)          16.304 ms           1.201 ms           0.940 ms    
(   100000,     1000)          15.185 ms           1.566 ms           1.181 ms    
(   100000,    10000)          15.914 ms           1.454 ms           1.252 ms    
(   100000,   100000)          23.719 ms           4.820 ms           4.313 ms    
(   100000,  1000000)         119.668 ms          56.863 ms          54.570 ms    
(  1000000,        1)           0.774 ms           4.347 ms           3.407 ms    
(  1000000,       10)           6.207 ms           8.793 ms           5.957 ms    
(  1000000,      100)         178.498 ms          13.104 ms           8.544 ms    
(  1000000,     1000)         169.022 ms          16.198 ms          10.283 ms    
(  1000000,    10000)         177.986 ms          13.243 ms           8.973 ms    
(  1000000,   100000)         177.989 ms          19.856 ms          13.898 ms    
(  1000000,  1000000)         283.207 ms          97.118 ms          84.332 ms
```

This shows that Numba and parallelization are quite beneficial for larger inputs, and becomes marginally less efficient for smaller inputs.
However, they still outperform `np.isin()` in **most** of the above tests.

Comment: That's very nice method but for small array, np.isin is more faster. I'll keep in mind. Thank you!
p.s. Can I get their indices?

Comment: @SYJeon You specifically asked for a method that was faster for large arrays (n > 1e8).

Comment: @SYJeon What do you mean? You could modify it to get the integer indices, otherwise you get the boolean array much like `np.isin()`. The integer indices can be obtained from the boolean array with `np.nonzero()`.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks for kind answer!

Comment: @SYJeon I added some tests for the smaller inputs. It seems to me that Numba-accelerated approaches outperform `np.isin()` for those test **most** of the times. I believe that the collision rate may play a stronger role than the input size in some cases.

Comment: For very large 2D arrays, this code (preceded and followed by a quick reshape to 1D) is giving me a speed boost by a factor of 50-100!

Comment: @norok2 why is the numba method so much faster than the numpy one? I suppose the numpy could be better optimized then?

Comment: @Kelthar `np.isin()` is more complex and offers more functionality than the Numba code I provided. This answers assumes that, like in the question, the extra functionality is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that suits your needs, but intersection of sets (`&`) looks faster. The downside is that you will only get elements, not their indices.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

num = int(1e7)
a = np.random.rand(int(num))
b = np.random.rand(int(num))

a_set = set(a)
b_set = set(b)
```

Timing sets intersection:

```py
ref=time.time()
print(a_set & b_set)
print(time.time()-ref,'sec')

>> set()
0.6486170291900635 sec
```

Timing `np.isin()`:

```
ref=time.time()
ainb = np.isin(a, b)
print( a[ainb] )
print(time.time()-ref,'sec')

>> []
4.06556510925293 sec
```

Comment: That is not timing the quite significant time it takes to create the `set`s

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
np.isin(a,b, kind='table')
```

[this was introduced in numpy 1.24](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

in my case it reduced the time from 30 sec to 10 sec.
(the other solutions mentioned here did not work for me)