# Is there a faster method than np.isin and np.where for large arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

I have a 1xN array A and a 2xM array B. I want to make two new 1xN arrays

- a boolean one that checks whether the first column of B is in A
- another one with entries i that are B[1,i] if B[0,i] is in A, and np.nan otherwise

Whatever method I use needs to be super fast as it’ll be called a lot. I can do the first part using this: [Is there method faster than np.isin for large array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007409/is-there-method-faster-than-np-isin-for-large-array)

But I’m stumped on a good way to do the second part. Here’s what I’ve got so far (adapting the code in the post above):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def isinvals(arr, vals):
    n = len(arr)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    result_vals = np.full(n, np.nan)
    set_vals = set(vals[0,:])
    list_vals = list(vals[0,:])
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        if arr[i] in set_vals:
            ind = list_vals.index(arr[i]) ## THIS LINE IS WAY TOO SLOW
            result[i] = True
            result_vals[i] = vals[1,ind]
    return result, result_vals


N = int(1e5)
M = int(20e3)
num_arr = 100e3
num_vals = 20e3
num_types = 6
arr = np.random.randint(0, num_arr, N)
vals_col1 = np.random.randint(0, num_vals, M)
vals_col2 = np.random.randint(0, num_types, M)
vals = np.array([vals_col1, vals_col2])

%timeit result, result_vals = isinvals(arr,vals)
46.4 ms ± 3.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The line I've marked above (`list_vals.index(arr[i])`) is the slow part. If I don't use that I can make a super fast version:

```
@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def isinvals_cheating(arr, vals):
    n = len(arr)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    result_vals = np.full(n, np.nan)
    set_vals = set(vals[0,:])
    list_vals = list(vals[0,:])
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        if arr[i] in set_vals:
            ind = 0 ## TEMPORARILY SETTING TO 0 TO INDICATE SPEED DIFFERENCE
            result[i] = True
            result_vals[i] = vals[1,ind]
    return result, result_vals

%timeit result, result_vals = isinvals_cheating(arr,vals)
1.13 ms ± 59.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

i.e. that single line is making it 40 times slower.

Any ideas? I've also tried using np.where() but it's even slower.

Comment: Keep in mind that `np.where` just finds the "True" values in an array.  You still have to construct that array using whatever comparison is right.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.in1d` to see how `numpy` does it.  If one array is much smaller than the other, it takes combines `arr1 == a[i]`, otherwise it uses `argsort`.

Comment: I know I can use `np.isin` or `np.in1d` to test whether each element of `vals[0,:]` is also present in `arr`, but there are two issues with this: firstly it's relatively slow as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007409/is-there-method-faster-than-np-isin-for-large-array, and secondly it doesn't help me get the values of `vals[1,:]` corresponding to entries of `vals[0,:]` that appear in `arr`. Maybe you could explain a bit how you think `argsort` would help? Thank you!

Comment: `index` does a linear search in the list which is not efficient. Why not storing the index in the associated set? Alternatively you can sort the values and use a binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming OP's solution gives the desired result since the question seems ambiguous for non-unique values ​​in `vals[0, idx]` with different corresponding values `vals[1, idx]`. A lookup table is faster, but needs `len(arr)` additional space.

```py
@nb.njit  # tested with numba 0.55.1
def isin_nb(arr, vals):
    lookup = np.empty(len(arr), np.float32)
    lookup.fill(np.nan)
    lookup[vals[0, ::-1]] = vals[1, ::-1]
    res_val = lookup[arr]
    return ~np.isnan(res_val), res_val
```

With the example data used in the question

```
res, res_val = isin_nb(arr, vals)
# %timeit 1000 loops, best of 5: 294 µs per loop
```

Asserting equal results

```
np.testing.assert_equal(res, result)
np.testing.assert_equal(res_val, result_vals)
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works exactly how I'd hoped. Just one follow-up: this won't work if `len(arr)< (len(vals[0,])`, right? Is there any way to adapt this so that it would still work?

Comment: This solution does not depend on the length of the arrays, but whether all elements are valid indices of the *lookup* array. However, this is not a general solution, but tailored to the specifics of the example data.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I ended up modifying your solution by passing `num_vals` into the `isin_nb()` as an additional argument, and then using `num_vals` instead of `len(arr)` in the first line. That way it will still work with `N=int(10e3)`, for example.

Comment: Some notes: using `np.full` might be faster and is also simpler. If there is no inf in the dataset, then using `np.isfinite` can be slightly faster than `~np.isnan`.