# Proper way to find array b in array a?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, geospatial

I have two numpy arrays of coordinates, `a (n, 2)` and `b (m, 2)`, where each row in both arrays correspond to `x` and `y` coordinates of a point:

```
a = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xn, yn]]
b = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xm, ym]]
```

I am trying to find an efficient way of creating a boolean mask where True corresponds to the occurrence of `b` in `a`. In theory, `b` should be a subset of `a`, but this condition is not certain. The solutions I've tried so far have given me too many results (i.e. > `b`), and I am not quite sure why. I would therefore like to ask for suggestions on what could be going on.

To summarize, I would like to achieve a mask so that

```
a[mask] = b
```

The data has been pre-processed to remove nan and infinity values. Because both `a` and `b` are very large, it is not feasible to just conduct an equality check using for loops:

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=bool)
for i, p1 in enumerate(a):
    for j, p2 in enumerate(b):
        if p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[1] == p2[1]:
            mask[i] = True
```

So I initially used `numpy's isin()` method:

```
mask = np.isin(a, b, assume_unique=False).all(axis=1)
print(mask.sum())
```

But this is where I instead of getting the expected output `m` get `m + k`, where `k` is several orders of magnitude smaller than `n` or `m`.

I have checked for duplicates in the arrays:

```
unique_a = np.unique(a, axis=0)
unique_b = np.unique(b, axis=0)
```

which shows that `b` has no duplicates and `a` does have a few, but still way less than the surplus `k`.

To verify that the error is indeed likely in the data and not the method of finding the included points, I tried another way (described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008597):

```
import numba as nb
@nb.jit
def is_in_set_nb(a, b):
    shape = a.shape
    a = a.ravel()
    n = len(a)
    result = np.full(n, False)
    set_b = set(b)
    for i in range(n):
        if a[i] in set_b:
            result[i] = True
    return result.reshape(shape)
mask_x = is_in_set_nb(a[:, 0], b[:, 0])
mask_y = is_in_set_nb(a[:, 1], b[:, 1])
mask = np.zeros((a.shape[0], ), dtype=bool)
mask[mask_x & mask_y] = True
print(mask.sum())
```

and also `numpy's in1d()` method

```
mask_x = np.in1d(a[:, 0].flatten(), b[:, 0].flatten())
mask_y = np.in1d(a[:, 1].flatten(), b[:, 1].flatten())
mask = np.zeros((a.shape[0], ), dtype=bool)
mask[mask_x & mask_y] = True
```

but these both give the same result of `m + k`.

To visually verify the data I exported `a[mask]` to `.gpkg` and opened it in QGIS. Using the vector difference tool I found that `a[mask]` has some extra points not found in `b`, and some other points from `b` are missing. These are in the same order of magnitude as `k`. However, importing these point sets into python and doing the same inclusion checks as above gives me a result indicating that the missing points are all included in `b`, but also some of the extra points, which should not be??

So really, my question is:

Is there something wrong with the data, or with the method, and if so then what?

Comment: For an element of `b` to be considered "in `a`", would that mean that both x *and* y match an element of `a`?

Comment: yeah, exactly, because the rows represent coordinates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.isin(a, b, assume_unique=False)` checks for inclusion elementwise: for each point `(x, y)` in `a`, it first checks whether `x` is somewhere in `b`, then whether `y` is somewhere in `b`.

The `.all(axis=1)` simply allows you to check that both `x` and `y` are present *somewhere* in `b`, but not necessarily on the same row.

To get the result you're expecting, use a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) [`view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) of the data so numpy can group it properly:

```py
point = np.dtype([('x', a.dtype), ('y', a.dtype)])
a_point = a.view(point).squeeze(-1)
b_point = b.view(point).squeeze(-1)
mask = np.isin(a_point, b_point, assume_unique=False)
```

Comment: This method worked, thank you for the answer and for clarifying what was wrong in the code I had!

Answer (score 0):

### Abstract

Both methods will give a different result from the expected one, but for different reasons.

### First method

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=bool)
for i, p1 in enumerate(a):
    for j, p2 in enumerate(b):
        if p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[1] == p2[1]:
            mask[i] = True
```

After `mask = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=bool)` mask will have shape (n, 2). Finally it will be, for example

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

So `mask.sum()` will give a number twice as large as expected

### Second method

```
mask = np.isin(a, b, assume_unique=False).all(axis=1)
print(mask.sum())
```

The problem with this method is that `np.isin` applies flatten to second array and as a result, not points are compared, but numbers of coordinates with numbers of other coordinates.

Example:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]])
b = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 1]])
display(np.isin(a, b, assume_unique=False))
```

Result:

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

As you can see, `[2, 0]` is compared with `set(0, 1, 2)`, not with `[[0, 1], [2, 1]]`

### Solution

The most efficient solution that takes advantage of numpy that I can offer:

```
(a[:, None] == b).all(-1).any(-1)
```

So here we still do element-wise comparison, but then we reduce it to expected 1-d mask

Comment: This solution unfortunately crashes for me, giving AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Are you trying exactly `(a[:, None] == b).all(-1).any(-1)` ? Cause `(a == b).all(-1).any(-1)` will definitely give this error.